# Find all subspace vectors

Tags: vector-spaces

There are two questions but I can do one and the second I don’t know how to do please kindly help me. Thankfully!!

1. Let $S=\{(x,0)\in\mathbb{R}^2, x\in\mathbb{R}\}$Prove that $S$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$
2. Find all vector subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$ containing $S$

---

For the Question (1) I can prove it. But Q2 I cannot,  please kindly show me how to find in a question (2).

---

Q1) Since $0=(0,0)\in S$

Let $ u=(a,0), v=(b,0)\in S, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$
$$u+\alpha v=(a,0)+\alpha(b,0)$$
$$u+\alpha v=( a+\alpha b, 0)\in S$$
Thus, $S$ is a subspace in $\mathbb{R}^2$

---

Additional
If $\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{K}$, Does the solution of this Q2 change ?

Remark $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}\or\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please show your attempt to prove question 1.

Comment: @Laufen, Do you see my attempt now ?

Comment: What are subspace vectors?

Comment: I can only imagine there is some language barrier or translation issues going on for question 2.  In English, the most common follow-up question would have been "*Find all* **subspaces of** $\Bbb R^2$ *which contain $S$ as a subset*" which you should recognize immediately is just $S$ and $\Bbb R^2$ themselves.

Comment: Vector subspace

Comment: @JMoravitz I mean like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, $S$ and $\Bbb R^2$ are subspaces of $\Bbb R^2$ which contain $S$. There are no others. If $T$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^2$ containing $S$, then $(1,0)\in T$. If $S\varsubsetneq T$, take $t\in T\setminus S$. Then $t=(x,y)$, with $x,y\in\Bbb R$ and $y\neq 0$. But then $(0,1)\in T$, since$$(0,1)=\frac1y\bigl((x,y)-(x,0)\bigr)\in T.$$Since $(1,0),(0,1)\in T$, $T=\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Yes, Can I ask you ? If $\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{K}$, does it change on the solution ?

Comment: What I did is valid for any field.

Comment: So the solution is still the same for all field.

Comment: To make clearly, can you explain me how does this question mean ? Thank in advance.

Comment: Which question?

Comment: Question 2 Find all subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. And what is the final of this exercise? I’m not sure about this question

Comment: What I did in my answer was to ask question 2: the set of all vector subspaces of $\Bbb R^2$ which contain $S$ is the set $\{S,\Bbb R^2\}$. What else do you want?

Comment: Why should we let $T$?

Comment: Could you explain me more about your solution? Thank in advance

Comment: I have no idea about the meaning of the question “Why should we let $T$?”

Comment: In your answer If $T$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^2$ containing $S$, then $(1,0)\in T$. If $S\varsubsetneq T$, take $t\in T\setminus S$. Then $t=(x,y)$, with $x,y\in\Bbb R$ and $y\neq 0$. But then $(0,1)\in T$, since$$(0,1)=\frac1y\bigl((x,y)-(x,0)\bigr)\in T.$$Since $(1,0),(0,1)\in T$, $T=\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Does I can check beside $(1,0)$ and instead with other like $(2,0)$ or other etc

Comment: Yes, you can work with $(2,0)$ instead of $(1,0)$, if you want it.

Comment: Yeah what is intention to check for $T$?

Comment: I took an arbitrary vector subspace $T$ of $\Bbb R^2$ containing $S$, and then I checked that $T=S$ or that $T=\Bbb R^2$.